# Is it possible to link a string to an int?

Tags: java

I want to be able to call on a certain int with the use of strings. So for instance

```
final int music = 0;
final int film = 1;
int[][] matrix = new int[2][2];
```

say I have a String m containing "music"
and a String f containing "film"

is there any way I could get this to work:

```
matrix[m][f] = 1;
```

Comment: Have you used `enums`.

Comment: I don't know which problem you are trying to solve, but I doubt that this is the way to do it.

Comment: `String m containing "music"`, please elaborate on how you would even store music in a `String` ... Why not use an `ArrayList` ? or maybe simply an `String[]`

Comment: I have not checked on enums, will do that. As to the problem I am trying to solve, I want to put a lot of ints in a matrix with having strings as the location.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I suppose the hashmap way is the smoothest way to go. Is there any way I can close the question?

Comment: I hope somebody gives this question an answer using a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` (a map of maps). You could easily use the existing Google Guava's [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) class for this purpose.

Comment: @Slanec but why? A Map in a Map seems a bit too much for me for this use case.

Comment: @Ben It behaves most accurately as the OP's described 2D(!) associative array. While your solution is probably OK for OP as it seems he doesn't need anything really advanced/solid, I would personally prefer a Table-like solution, or at least making a `Map<FilmMusicKey, Integer>` where a `FilmMusicKey` is a specialized pair class (a good job for [Google AutoValue](http://goo.gl/Ter394)?) that would enable you to accurately describe all the behaviour you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also suggest a HashMap like Prashant, but like the following:

```
String music = "music";
String film = "film";
int numberForMusic = 0;
int numberForFilm = 1;
HashMap<String,Integer> matrix = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    matrix.put(music + "_" + film, numberForMusic+numberForFilm);
```

This way you can retrieve the `int 1` through simply combining your keys with any syntax, e.g. in my example through an underscore `_`.

OR

you could also just do the same as Prashant did and add each key alone:

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> matrix = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    matrix.put("music", 0);
    matrix.put("film", 1);
```

and then retrieving both values for these keys and just adding them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use HashMap:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> matrix = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        matrix.put("music", 1);
        matrix.put("film", 2);

        String m = "music";
        System.out.println(matrix.get(m));
```

Comment: But he wants "music" AND "film" as the key for `int` 1

Answer (score 0):

It is really unclear what you're trying to achieve, so I'm just guessing you need one of these approaches to pair an `int` to `String`..

Using a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> matrix = new HashMap<>();
matrix.put("SomeString", 1);

System.out.println(matrix.get("SomeString")); // will print out 1
```

Using Enumerations:

```
public enum Foo{

    SOMESTRING(1);

    private final int value;

    private Foo(int n){
        value = n;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}

System.out.println(Foo.SOMESTRING.getValue()); // print out 1
```

Docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

If you need to dynamically add/change the assignements go for the HashMap.